# Bad ping results while testing 6000 TCP clients with 18 mbytes/s total traffic on Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, tcp, ping, load-testing

The clients are running on the machine #1. The server is installed on the machine #2. The machines have a gigabit connection through a switch on their private vlan. There are no errors in the switch log. The clients and ping command use internal IP address. The CPU load on both machines is lower than 50% but rarely spikes to 100%.

Usually ping tells <1ms but randomly "Request timed out" or something like 400ms.

I see better results (70ms spikes) when I ping from another machine but when I connect more clients another machine shows "Request timed out" too.

There are no related warning in the windows event log.

What can cause that?

Comment: What is a "bad ping"? If it misbehaves, tell it to be nice...

Comment: updated the question

Comment: Check the switch statistics for dropped packets or other errors. Do you really have 6000 clients on a single switch?

Comment: @mfinni yes, 6000 on a single switch. is it a problem? I expect to make our server to handle 10k at least.

Comment: I don't know if it's a problem - I'm suggesting that you start troubleshooting the switch to see if it's a problem. I'm surprised to hear that there's a switch with 6000 ports - what make and model is it? Have you checked the switch statistics, as I suggested? Are you using multiple VLANs? Tell us more about the environment.

Comment: 6000 connections doesn't mean 6000 ports on the switch

Comment: @mfinni there are no errors in the switch log

Comment: The way you've written the question, it's very ambiguous. What is directly attached to "the switch" - the server, some of the clients, all of the clients? What log did you review? What do the statistics say?

Comment: ok, I updated the question again. I can't tell more about the switch because we are using hosting services. Their admin rechecked switch several times for any errors in the log and resources usage.

Comment: @vlad If you're troubleshooting the performance of a network you have no actual infrastructural access to, you might want to step back and review if you're the best person for the job. Can you say with absolute certainty that there is only one switch involved?

Comment: @Reaces I'm the developer of the server app, that's why I'm asking. I'll clarify if there is only one switch involved.